# Lagrangian for second-order system

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism, variational-principle, dissipation

Given an $n$-dimensional second-order system
$$\ddot q^i-\sum_{j=1}^n A^i_j\dot q^j=0,$$
where $A$ is a constant matrix, is it possible to find a Lagrangian such that the above equation is the associated Euler-Lagrange equation? I obtain one result when $A$ is symmetric, that is, $$L=\frac12\dot qe^{-tA}\dot q.$$ But according to [Douglas' theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_problem_for_Lagrangian_mechanics#Douglas.27_theorem_and_the_Helmholtz_conditions), it is possible to find one when $A$ is skew-symmetric. So I want to know how to find for skew-symmetric $A$ and, if it possible, for general $A$.

Answer (score 2):

Partial answers:

1. For skew-symmetric $A$, then a possible action is 
   $$\tag{1}S[q]~=~\int \!dt~ L, \qquad  L~=~\frac{1}{2}\dot{q}^T\dot{q}+\frac{1}{2}q^TA\dot{q}$$
2. If one is allowed to use Lagrange multipliers $\lambda_i$, then a possible action is 
   $$\tag{2}S[q,\lambda]~=~\int \!dt~ L, \qquad L~=~\lambda^T(-\ddot{q}+A\dot{q})~\sim~\dot{\lambda}^T\dot{q}+\lambda^TA\dot{q},$$ 
   where $\sim$ denotes equality up to a total time derivative.

Comment: Wow, how did you find it for skew-symmetric A? For general $A$, I think that Lagrangian you gave generates a trivial EL equation (0=0).

Comment: 1. For some physical intuition: in 3D the matrix $A$ plays the role of a Levi-Civita-dualized magnetic field. 2. No, the EL eqs do not vanish identically.